# Pygame, выполнить команду после того, как звук проиграется полностью

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pygame

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что нужно сделать, чтобы следующая команда выполнялась только после того, как звук проиграется полностью.

Например, я хочу, чтобы после проигрывания звукового файла число в заголовке tkinter увеличивалось на 1.

Но если сделать вот так:

```
import tkinter as tk
import pygame

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry ("500x500")
pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, -16, 1, 512)
pygame.init()
test = pygame.mixer.Sound("5.wav")

for a in range(1, 11):
    test.play()
    root.title(str(a))
root.mainloop()
```

то число начнёт увеличиваться на 1 сразу же после начала проигрывания файла, не дождавшись его окончания. Более того, сразу же после увеличения числа звук начнёт проигрываться сразу же, и в результате получается какофония.

А как надо правильно сделать? Если что, этот код я писал под Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Уточните, сколько раз нужно чтобы проигрывался звук, по вашему коду как буд-то 10 раз все верно? Кстати хотелось бы понимать, Вы же видите что ваш цикл срабатывает до того как отобразится окно, поэтому и заголовок покажется уже готовым. В связи с этим если не сложно опишите полностью как должна работать программа, например: появится окно, и 10 раз последовательно проиграется звук и увеличится число в заголовке

Comment: Вы поняли всё правильно. Разве что при закрытии окна не должно быть ошибок, а у меня что-то выскакивало. Я немного подстроил под себя Ваше решение, добавив условие, что при a>=10 выполняется оператор break, а в конце всей программы я добавил root.mainloop(). И всё работает именно так, как я и хотел. Выложить то, что получилось? И большое Вам спасибо!

Comment: Рад, что получилось помочь, да можете в качестве отдельного ответа выложить свое решение, так делают.

Comment: Я обновил свой ответ чтобы не выбивалась ошибка при закрытии

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот код который проигрывает файл 10 раз:

```
import tkinter as tk
import pygame

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry ("500x500")
pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, -16, 1, 512)
pygame.init()

run = True

def stop():
    global run
    run = False

root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", stop)

test = pygame.mixer.Sound("5.wav")

a = 0

while run:
    root.update_idletasks()
    root.update()
    if (a < 10 and not pygame.mixer.get_busy()):
      test.play()
      root.title(str(a))
      a += 1
```

Обратите внимание что я заменил:
`root.mainloop()`
на

```
while True:
    root.update_idletasks()
    root.update()
```

таким образом проигрывание звука происходит в `основном цикле`, а не до, как это было в приведенном в вопросе коде. И вместо цикла `for` используется тот же `while` для `основного цикла`, ограничения задаются условием `if a < 10` , а так же мы проверяем не проигрывается ли сейчас звук `not pygame.mixer.get_busy()` т.е. дожидаемся когда он проиграется и лишь затем выполняем действия.